# Is there a way to preprocess ruby code and find errors that would occur runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

We have huge code base and we are generating issues that would have been caught at compile time in type languages such as Java but we are not catching them until runtime in Ruby. This is bad since we generate bugs that most of the time are typos or refactoring that leaves some invalid code.

Example:

```
def mysuperfunc
    # some code goes here

    # this was a valid call but not anymore since enforcesecurity
    # signature changed
    @system.enforcesecurity
end
```

I mean, IDEs can do it but some guys use ATOM or sublime, so we need something to "compile" and report that kind of issues so they don't reach deployment. What have you been using?

This is generating a little percentage of our bug reports, but since we are forced to produce at a ridiculous pace we don't have 100% code coverage. If there is no tool to help, I'll just make sure everybody uses and IDE and run the reports with tools such as Rubymine.

Our stack includes, rspec, minitest, SimpleCov. We enforce code reviews, multistack deployments (dev, qa, pre-prod, sandbox, prod). And still some issues are reaching higher level and makes us programmers look bad. I'm not looking of magic, just a little automation that might help a bit.

Comment: no, there isn't a gem to magically make ruby into a statically typed language, which seems to be what you are asking. Are you writing tests? I believe writing tests is considered required practice even in Java, but it's especially important in a non-statically typed language like ruby.

Comment: there are tools that can help you, but in the end ruby is dynamic typed so you need to have more tests for this cases, check: https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint

Comment: In ruby the best bet is to write tests and run some code coverage tools like simple_cov or coveralls. This will give you an idea of how much code is covered by your testing suites. Since ruby uses duck typing a pre-compiler would have one hell of time passing in numerous objects that respond to the  called methods to see if they fail anywhere in the chain and even the best it could do is say you can't use object X but objects A-W might still be acceptable.

Comment: The first step of any refactoring should be to write tests if they don't exist. Refactoring without tests to verify before/after equality will nearly always take longer than writing those tests at the beginning.

Comment: Using something like SimpleCov is probably your best bet. You can leverage things like ctags to make sure definitions exist for methods (although it would be spotty given Ruby is highly dynamic). Honestly though, my advice would be simple code, better testing, and fast-feedback reporting when things do hit prod

Comment: Tests catch things early on.  Just about any test at all of your example `mysuperfunc` would catch that `@system.enforcesecurity` would raise, for your example. There's a reason most of the answers here suggest writing tests. There's no way to make ruby a statically typed language. If management won't let you do what's needed to have good code, then you won't. shrug. I did not mean to be insulting,not sure what about it was, but sorry.There are no solutions I am aware of for ruby that will catch type errors statically. I was not aware RubyMine could do it though, perhaps you can automate that?

Comment: In Ruby it's not possible to catch that sort of error in the general case, not just because the type (and thus interface) of `@system` is not known until run-time, but because even if you knew the exact value of `@system` (for instance if you were calling a method on a string literal), the method signature of any method can change at run time. A static analysis tool could warn that a given method on a given object _probably maybe_ required more parameters than you gave, but when working with any sort of codebase involving extensive metaprogramming it would likely be wrong a lot of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Halting Problem, Rice's Theorem, and all the other Undecidability and Uncomputability Results tell us that it is simply impossible in the general case to statically determine *any* "interesting" property about the runtime behavior of a program. We cannot even statically determine something as simple as "will it halt", so how are we going to determine "is bug-free"?

There *are* certain things that *can* be statically determined, and there are certain restricted programs for which some interesting properties can be statically determined, but largely, this is not possible. And even to the small extent that it *is* possible, it generally requires the language to be specifically designed to be easy to statically analyze (which Ruby isn't).

That being said, there are certain tools that contain certain *heuristics* to point out code that *may* have problems. There are certain coding standards that may help avoid bugs, and there are tools to enforce those coding standards. Keywords to search for are "code quality tools", "linter", "static analyzer", etc. You have already been given examples in the other answers and comments, and given those examples and these keywords, you'll likely find more.

However, I also wanted to discuss something you wrote:

> we are forced to produce at a ridiculous pace we don't have 100% code coverage

That's a problem, which has to be approached from two sides:

1. Practice, practice, practice. You need to practice testing and writing high-quality code until it is *so* naturally to you that *not* doing it actually ends up being harder and slower. It should become second nature to you, such that under pressure when your mind goes blank, the *only* thing you know is to write tests and write well-designed, well-factored, high-quality code. Note: I'm talking about *deliberate practice*, which means setting time aside to *really* practice … and practice is *practice*, it's not work, it's not fun, it's not hobby, if you don't delete the code you wrote immediately after you have written it, you are not practicing, you are working.
2. Sustainable Pace. You should *never* develop faster than the pace you could sustain indefinitely while still producing well-tested, well-designed, well-factored, high-quality code, having a fulfilling social life, no stress, plenty of free time, etc. This is something that has to be backed and supported and understood by management.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unaware of anything exactly like you want. However, there are a few gems that will analyze code and warn you about some errors and/or bad practices. Try these:

- https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop
- https://github.com/railsbp/rails_best_practices

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/troessner/reek. It does help in a "sonar" or "code climate" way.

Answer (score 2):

**FLAY**

https://rubygems.org/gems/flay

Via the repo https://github.com/seattlerb/flay:

> DESCRIPTION:
>
> Flay analyzes code for structural similarities. Differences in literal
>   values, variable, class, method names, whitespace, programming style,
>   braces vs do/end, etc are all ignored. Making this totally rad.
>
> [FEATURES:]
>
> - Reports differences at any level of code.
> - Adds a score multiplier to identical nodes.
> - Differences in literal values, variable, class, and method names are ignored.
> - Differences in whitespace, programming style, braces vs do/end, etc are ignored.
> - Works across files.
>
>   - Add the flay-persistent plugin to work across large/many projects.
> - Run `--diff` to see an N-way diff of the code.
> - Provides conservative (default) and `--liberal` pruning options.
> - Provides `--fuzzy` duplication detection.
> - Language independent: Plugin system allows other languages to be flayed.
>
>   - Ships with `.rb` and `.erb`.
>   - javascript and others will be
>       available separately.
> - Includes `FlayTask` for Rakefiles.
> - Uses `path_expander`, so you can use:
>
>   - `dir_arg` -- expand a directory automatically
>   - `@file_of_args` -- persist arguments in a file
>   - `-path_to_subtract` -- ignore intersecting subsets of
>       files/directories
> - Skips files matched via patterns in `.flayignore` (subset format of `.gitignore`).
> - Totally rad.

---

**FLOG**

https://rubygems.org/gems/flog

Via the repo https://github.com/seattlerb/flog:

> DESCRIPTION:
>
> Flog reports the most tortured code in an easy to read pain report.
>   The higher the score, the more pain the code is in.
>
> [FEATURES:]
>
> - Easy to read reporting of complexity/pain.
> - Uses `path_expander`, so you can use:
>
>   - `dir_arg` – expand a directory automatically
>   - `@file_of_args` – persist arguments in a file
>   - `-path_to_subtract` – ignore intersecting subsets of files/directories
>
> SYNOPSIS:
>
> ```
> % ./bin/flog -g lib
> Total Flog = 1097.2 (17.4 flog / method)
>
>    323.8: Flog total
>     85.3: Flog#output_details
>     61.9: Flog#process_iter
>     53.7: Flog#parse_options
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is a ruby gem called guard that does automated testing. You can set your own custom rules.

For example, you can make it where anytime you modify certain files, the test framework will automatically run.

Here is the link for [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard)